# Lookup across multiple tables in Acumatica ReportDesigner

Tags: acumatica

I am working on a sales order confirmation report, and in the Mailing Settings I am attempting to get contact information (email, phone, etc) for the default Salesperson set on the SO.

The SalespersonID on the SO corresponds to SalespersonID on the EPEmployee table, and from there the UserID on the EPEmployee table corresponds to the UserID on the Contact table.

I'm not having any luck defining this sequence of joins in my report schema builder, though.  Is this possible, and if so how should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard Sales Order report already has joins for EMEmployee to the OwnerID of the Sales Order, and Contact to the Default Contact for the Customer.

You can add additional joins by using the child table alias in the Schema Relationship for EPEmployee and Contact. 
[image]
[image]

With these joins using the SalesPersonContact table alias in the Expression editor allows you to get the contact information in the Mailing settings.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't have my head wrapped around using the aliased table to define the relationship join.  That did the trick!